# Box API get shared file results in 404

Tags: box-api, box

Already looked at [How to use box-api to get the Shared item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004157/how-to-use-box-api-to-get-the-shared-item) and Box Developers documentation https://developers.box.com/docs/#shared-items.  I have tried doing a request to https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items in .NET code, in Firefox Poster and using curl.  They all resulted in 404.  I have verified that my file's shared link is open to anyone with a link.  Here's my curl code (sanitized):

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items -H "Authorization: Bo
xAuth api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "BoxApi: shared_link=https://
app.box.com/s/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

{"type":"error","status":404,"code":"not_found","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.
box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Not Found","request_id":"196207167555469c3017
14b"}
```

What might be the problem?  I tried a wrong api_key and got back 401 so I know the whole setup is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your API key shouldn't be included anywhere in the request. I believe that form of authorization was used in the old v1 API and is now deprecated. There's a cURL example in [the docs you linked to](https://developers.box.com/docs/#shared-items-get-a-shared-item) that shows what your authorization header should look like:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_CODE"
-H "BoxApi: shared_link=SHARED_LINK"
```

For more info on how to obtain the access token that goes into the authorization header, take a look at the [OAuth tutorial](https://developers.box.com/oauth/).

The reason why authentication is required is because the API will return info about the item within the context of the caller's permissions. For example, if the creator of the shared link makes the API call, then private information (such as the item's full path within their account) will be returned. If another user makes the call, then that private information will be omitted.

That being said, you're still able to anonymously download an open shared link by navigating to it directly. You only need to use the API if you want more information about the item that the link points to.

Comment: thanks. Yes I saw the documentation has the Bearer authorization in the header. In my case, it is a public share link, that is, ANYONE with the link can access the file without login or password. Why do I have to go through the oAuth to authenticate and get an Access Code?  The whole point is to surface such files in my web app without bothering users with login.

Comment: I added an explanation for why authentication is required.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the further details.  However, consider this use case: I'd like to serve files from my website without visitors to my site knowing that the files are stored at Box.  How can I authenticate to Box behind the scene?  The visitors to my site may not have a Box account or they may be behind corporate network that blocks Box.com.  That is, linking to box url or embedding box on my site is not an option.  Hence the need to serve up files from my website via Box API.  If Box API does not support such a scenario that's fine.  I just need to know.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can have your server authenticate using your own Box account so it has access to the files that you need to serve. If you're concerned about your users being behind a firewall, then you don't have too many options other than to proxy downloads and uploads through your own server.

Comment: As far as I can tell, server to server application authentication is not support by Box API.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582381/2-legged-flow-for-service-account-authentication-box is a bit old but seems to support what I have found so far.